# Does Parse.Cloud.httpRequest count as a Parse API request?

Tags: parse-platform, httprequest, parse-cloud-code

Does Parse.Cloud.httpRequest count as a Parse API request? For example:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'http://www.parse.com/'
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
  // success
  console.log(httpResponse.text);
},function(httpResponse) {
  // error
  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

On Parse's website it states:

> Anytime you make a network call to Parse on behalf of your app using
>   one of the Parse SDKs or REST API, it counts as an API request. This
>   does include things like queries, saves, logins, amongst other kinds
>   of requests.

I am unsure as to whether this counts as 'other kinds of requests', seeing as the Parse object is being used.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some testing I discovered that Parse.Cloud.httpRequest does NOT count as a Parse API request.